# How do I add Widgets to my theme and activate them on my site?

Tags: widgets

I registered the widget area in my functions.php and they appear in my admin area but when I drag it over to the right hand panel to make changes none of them seem to do anything.

Anyone know what I can do to find a solution to this problem?

The widget in question is WP YouTube Lyte

Edit:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', array(&$this,'arphabet_widgets_init'));
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Home right sidebar',
        'id' => 'home_right_1',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Show us the code of the template that is running the widget area. As well as the accompanying registration code.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without seeing your actual code.

Comment: I've added the registration code, but what do you mean by the template code?

Comment: That code registers a dynamic sidebar area. It's one of three parts of potential code: 1) registering the sidebar area (which you have here), 2) Outputting the sidebar area in the template (via `dynamic_sidebar()` call), and 3) Defining custom widgets (if applicable).

Comment: Ah....... that would be the problem.

Comment: @ChipBennett How do I find out the name to call the widget, I assume thery're not all called dynamic_sidebar?

Comment: Perhaps you could **edit your question**, and describe in more detail what exactly you're trying to do? If you're trying to add a new widget area (dynamic sidebar) to a Theme, please clarify in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to [**add a new widget area (dynamic sidebar)** to your Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sidebars).

That process has three parts:

1. Register the dynamic sidebar in `functions.php`, using [`register_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar):

   ```
    function wpse121723_register_sidebars() {
        register_sidebar( array(
            'name' => 'Home right sidebar',
            'id' => 'home_right_1',
            'before_widget' => '<div>',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
            'after_title' => '</h2>',
        ) );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpse121723_register_sidebars' );
   ```

   This registers the dynamic sidebar with WordPress, which displays its UI in `Appearance -> Widgets` in the Admin. The important part here is the `id` parameter, which you'll use in the next step:
2. Output the widget area (dynamic sidebar) in your Theme template, wherever appropriate, using [`dynamic_sidebar( $id )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar):

   ```
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ); ?>
   ```

   This actually displays the dynamic sidebar in the template.
3. Populate the dynamic sidebar, via `Appearance -> Widgets` in the Admin.

It sounds like you've done #1 and #3, but not #2.

Comment: I seemed to have completely glossed over a lot of what actually was involved in using widgets, I basically assumed I just had to activate it and then it would automagically work. The widget I want to use is called WP YouTube Lyte.

Comment: You should be able to add any given Widget to any given Widget area (dynamic sidebar).

Comment: I'm with it now :D it's working, thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you for your helping answer. Under point 2. of it you made a typo. "dymamic". Threw an error here and then I saw it was spelled with an "m".